# Windows Server 2003: Remapping external domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, redirect

We're playing a going-away prank on a coworker, and would like to use a rule in our internal DNS server to redirect techcrunch.com to point at one of our internal development servers.  Basically, I'd like to accomplish the same thing as adding a line to a Linux /etc/hosts file, only for the entire network.

I have access to our DNS server. How would you go about doing this?

I created an entry in the reverse lookup subnet with the 'Host Name' of techcrunch.com and the 'Host IP' of our development server, a Linux box running Debian on which I've created a virtualhost to handle requests to techcrunch.com. It doesn't appear to be working, however, and my expertise has reached its limit.

Thanks!

Comment: HAHAHAHA! AMAZING!

Comment: You are an inspiration to us all.  Now, you just need to add content that is believable, but wrong.  "Google buys Apple Fabrication Plant", "MS sues Apple over Bootcamp 'enabling piracy'", etc.

Comment: It was a brilliantly designed and executed prank (if I do say so myself) that was foiled by the target's laziness. He was sshed into a client server at the time, so he used lynx to open the link, using the client server as a proxy and bypassing our DNS server. Drats! I plan on blogging about this and will post a link here when I do. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to create a normal primary DNS Zone (with Active Directory integration disabled). Call it "techcrunch.com" (note that there is no trailing period).

Create a CNAME record in that zone, and point it to the HOST record of the machine on the
local LAN.

Be careful. As far as the DNS is concerned you're now authoritative for techcrunch.com, so if there are subnets, etc, etc, then you're going to need to put in names for them as well.

Comment: Exactly what we did, thanks! Fortunately TechCrunch is on Wordpress.com, so its DNS setup should be very simple.